# In "the Prestige", why the clone does not show off in the last spectacle?

Tags: the-prestige

In my understanding, the character played by Hugh Jackman kills himself every night, while a clone appears at the other side of the theater.

But, one night, the second magician, played by Christian Bale, is too curious and goes down to see Jackman's drowning. To trick Bale, the clone does not appear this time. How could the clone know that this evening Bale will go under the stage?

Comment: Saw him in the audience, probably

Comment: Bales character is one of those who go up on stage to check the equipment as well, so it's not as if he's lingering at the back of the audience - Jackmans character knows that he's intrigued his rival to the point where he's taking a direct interest in how the trick is done, especially considering that the trick is not a direct copy of the original, but it includes an impossible distance teleportation as well which wouldn't be explained by a trapdoor or other usual device.